# Auto Image Resize coding html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image responsive in my responsive website as my theme is also responsive. But I am struggling to find a solution which fits my needs.
Here is my code

```css
#payment_wrapper img {
  width: 375px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="payment_wrapper">
<img title="Payment" alt="Payment"  src="{{media url="payment.png}}"  />
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.mysite.co.uk/"> <img  title=" image2 " alt=" image2" src="{{media url="image2.png}}" /> </a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mysite.co.uk"> <img title=" image3" alt=" image3 " src="{{media url="image3.png}}"  />
</div>
```

Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong?
Before anybody mark it as a duplicate post, know that I have tried other posts and all the solutions mentioned in those posts, but none is working for me.

if I just set `width: 100%` my image goes too big, if I set `max-width: 375px;` it does not response.
Can you tell me what is the correct way to write the above code.

Your help in this matter will be appreciated,

Comment: Can you add some placeholder images so we can see how your site looks? Try using http://placehold.it/

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, and perhaps give us an example that can show the images?

Comment: @gaynorvader you an check the images in my sites footer here (http://www.smartteck.co.uk/) its the world pay image i am talking abount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting it up so that all your images remain relatively the same size as they shrink by setting their max-width as percentages.

```
#payment_wrapper img{/*2 smaller images (100px)*/
    max-width: 16%;
}
#payment_wrapper img.payment_wrapper{/*Larger image (375px)*/
    max-width: 65%;
}
```

You can prevent them from shrinking too small by adding a minimum width to your container.

```
#payment_wrapper{
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

For an example, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj8r15ue/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still not re sizing in my site, what i am doing wrong? lost all my hairs now.

Comment: Try putting the css code in style tags at the top. You have a lot of css files being loaded and your images don't seem to be picking up the style so it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change width in `.footer-bottom .item`

```
.footer-bottom .item {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `img` in blocks and set `max-width` on them.

Note the `<div>` tag around the first image and the `a { display: block; }`.

```css
#payment_wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div, a {
  display: block;  
}

#payment_wrapper > *:nth-child(1) {
  max-width: 600px;
}

#payment_wrapper > *:nth-child(2) {
  max-width: 500px;
}

#payment_wrapper > *:nth-child(3) {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="payment_wrapper">
<div><img title="Payment" alt="Payment"  src="http://placehold.it/600x300"  /></div>
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.mysite.co.uk/"> <img  title=" image2 " alt=" image2" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" /> </a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mysite.co.uk"> <img title=" image3" alt=" image3 " src="http://placehold.it/400x300"  /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still does not seem to be working on my site, even though testing this code seems working here.

Comment: Okay, what differences can you note between the code above and your code?

Answer (score 0):

Set only max-width:100% so that it will not overflow the outer container on smaller devices. Don't set width to the image to make it responsive.

```
#payment_wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: tried that but image goes too big, i need to limit image size, the original image size is 375x70 pixels but when i set max-width: 100% it goes 50 times bigger the original size.

Comment: Can you resize the image on photoshop in constant proportions means set the width to "375px" and adjust the height automatically...